# Can the double integral of a positive function over a rectangle ever be negative?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

I understand that if a function is ever negative, then the double integral can be considered a “signed” volume and thus having a negative volume is possible. Does the same apply to a positive function if, for instance, the rectangle is bounded by negative $x$ and $y$ values?

Comment: Compare this to the lower dimensional analog/single integral and area.

Comment: The general answer is: no, it is not possible that the double integral of a positive function over a rectangle results in a negative value. The only exception I know is when the integration has the wrong orientation; for example when you integrate $x$ from 0 to 1 and $y$ from 1 to 0. That way you introduce a minus sign.

Comment: We say $\int_a^b f(x) \,dx = -\int_b^a f(x)\,dx$.  That is the sense such an integral could be negative even if $f > 0$.  Perhaps in the future you will learn about the mathematical concept called "orientation".